# Initialize influxdb2 buckets with entrypoint script

Tags: docker, influxdb, influxdb-2

I am working on a deployment of an influxdb for storing of real-time data. I have been using 1.8.4 for some time now and recently decided to update to v2.

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks something like this:

```yaml
influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.0.4-alpine
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    volumes:
      - ./influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb2
      - ./influxdb/config:/etc/influxdb2
      - ./influxdb/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=${INFLUXDB_USR}
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=${INFLUXDB_PWD}
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=Org0
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=bucket0
```

which indeed creates an initial bucket named `bucket0`.

That said I would like to have a script in order to initialize further buckets, write some data or add auth. In my `./influxdb/scripts` directory I have a script `init.sh` which would look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
influx bucket create -n bucket1 -d "Bucket 1"
```

Then I would continue to use `influx write` and `influx auth` and all the nice stuff that influx cli provides, but the script above seems to not have any effect creating the bucket.

I have also tried to use the `-c /etc/influxdb2/influx-configs` option or the `--token` to no avail.

Doing a `docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash` and then executing the exact same command created the bucket as expected.

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to run the following script at influxdb startup :

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
influx bucket create -n first -r 7d
influx bucket create -n second -r 7d
```

- even if the influxdb docker image supports bash, you should prefer writing sh scripts for alpine.
- is your script executable ? (chmod +x init.sh)
- the init.sh script is executed only the first time influxdb is launched. Once initialized, you must clean your docker volumes associated with this image. If you use docker-compose : docker-compose down -v

Best regards